# How can I pass information from a text field when I click a button with the builder?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivymd

I´m new using kivymd and trying to create a simple app, just for fun. I´m trying to create a register screen, but when I try to send the info to the console it returns me an error (kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**') and I actually don´t understand what it means.

.PY

'''

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRoundFlatButton
from screen_helper import screen_helper
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (300, 500)

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass        

class RegistrarScreen(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='login'))
sm.add_widget(RegistrarScreen(name='registrar'))

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Gray'
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper) 
        return screen

    def show_data(self):
        print(self.root.ids.user.text)
    
        
MainApp().run()
```

'''

.KV

'''

```
screen_helper = """

ScreenManager:
    RegistrarScreen:


<RegistrarScreen>:
    name: "register"
    MDTextField:
        id: user
        hint_text: 'Enter your user'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y': 0.8}
        size_hint_x: None 
        width: 250  

    MDRoundFlatButton:
        id: register_btn
        text: "Registrarse"
        text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        line_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y': 0.1}
        width: 500
        on_press: app.show_data()
"""
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `show_data()` method is trying to access `self.root.ids.user`, but that `id` is not in the `self.root` widget (which is the `ScreenManager`). Try changing that method to:

```
def show_data(self):
    print(self.root.get_screen('register').ids.user.text)
```

Comment: As you said, that was the problem. I just changed that and resolved my problem. Thank you.